# Matplotlib condenses two separate figures into one upon saving them

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, save

I am new to Python. When running these lines of code, I expect two separate figures to be saved.

**Figure no. 1:**

```
#3) Create the graph
N=int(raw_input('Number of nodes (sqrt): '))
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels,with_labels=False, node_size=10)
#Plot the graph
plt.axis('off')
title_string=('Lattice Network') 
subtitle_string=(''+str(N)+'x'+str(N)+' = '+str(N*N)+' nodes')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)
plt.savefig('100x100_lattice.png', dpi=1000,bbox='tight') #Figure no. 1
plt.close()
```

**Figure no. 2:**

```
#4) Plot the degree distribution
for data_dict in node_degree.values():
    x=node_degree.keys()
    y=node_degree.values()
from collections import Counter
occ=Counter(y)
for data_dict in occ.values():
    plotx=occ.keys()
    ploty=occ.values()
Pk=numpy.zeros((len(ploty)))
for i in range(0, len(ploty)):
    Pk[i]=numpy.around(ploty[i]/(N*N),3)
plt.scatter(plotx,Pk,color='red', edgecolors='darkred')
plt.show() 
plt.xlabel('Node degree k')
plt.ylabel('P(k)')
plt.xlim(0,10,1)
plt.xticks(numpy.arange(0, 11, 1.0))
plt.ylim(0,1) 
plt.yticks(numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
title_string=('Degree Distribution')
subtitle_string=('Lattice, '+str(N)+'x'+str(N)+' nodes') 
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=9)
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='on',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='on',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='on')
plt.savefig('100x100_lattice_Degree_Distrib.png', dpi=1000,bbox='tight') #Figure no. 2
plt.close()
```

Instead, what I visually get is:

[image]

**My problem.** The image to the right (in the code, `Figure no. 2`) is correct. The one to the left (`Figure no. 1`) is wrong, in that it should only show the regular structure you see and not the red dots, which obviously come from the second image. There must be something wrong in my `plt.show` calls, but I can't find an answer. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that plt.scatter() in your second figure is drawing to the figure that was created in your first figure, right?  Just add a call to plt.figure() before your call to plt.scatter() in the second figure. That should fix your problem here.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I assume the take-home message is: *each time you want to plot something in matplotlib, make sure you call* `plt.figure()` *before any new plot*.

Comment: an even better take home message is use the object-oriented interface: `fig=plt.figure(); ax=fig.add_subplot(111); ax.scatter(...)`. That way you always know which `Axes` you are plotting on

Comment: what @tom said. really, you should just avoid using `plt` entirely except to create figures and axes